# How to make a custom view inherit it's parent's style in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-switch

With a Switch I can do this:

```
< Switch
                android:id="@+id/normal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:switchPadding="16dp"
                android:thumbTextPadding="16dp"
                android:text="Hello World" />
```

Pay attention to this lines:

```
android:switchPadding="16dp"
                    android:thumbTextPadding="16dp"
```

Now, I made a custom view that extends this Switch. I didn't made any special change:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat


class BetterSwitchCompat : SwitchCompat {
    private var listener: OnCheckedChangeListener? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
            : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener: OnCheckedChangeListener?) {
        if (listener != null) {
            this.listener = listener
        }
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)
    }

    fun setCheckedSilent(checked: Boolean) {
        toggleListener(false)
        isChecked = checked
        toggleListener(true)
    }

    private fun toggleListener(value: Boolean) {
        if (value) setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)
        else setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing more than a business logic for **check** method.

Why I can't use the attributes I referred to before for the new class?

There are just a few posts about this, but none of them clarify what I am asking.

1. [Android custom view inherit all styles and attributes from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051920/android-custom-view-inherit-all-styles-and-attributes-from-parent)
2. [How to make a custom view inherit it's parent's style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418784/how-to-make-a-custom-view-inherit-its-parents-style)

Comment: Just a guess: try adding the fourth View constructor `context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` isn't `SwitchCompat`. `SwitchCompat` comes from AndroidX so it uses application-defined attributes.

Try prefixing the attributes in question with `app:` instead of `android:`, such as `app:switchPadding`.

Comment: You're right. Switch is not the same as SwitchCompat. It was my mistake. Thank you very much, friend.